# Pullback of a translation map of a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry, pullback

Let X be an elliptic curve, D be a divisor on X with degree 0.
Then $\tau^{*}_{Q} D = D $ for all $Q \in X$.
Is this true?

$\tau_Q$ is a translation map defined by $X \rightarrow X, P \mapsto P+Q$ and $\tau^{*}_Q$ is the pullback.

Answer (score 3):

I always find these sorts of questions tricky because there are two group operations:

- the addition of divisors modulo linear equivalence, within the group $Pic(X)$;
- the elliptic curve group law.

These two group operations are closely related, and before we can answer your question, we need to spell out exactly how they are related:

Fix a "zero point" $p_0$ on the elliptic curve $X$. Let $Pic^0(X)$ denote the group of degree-zero divisors on $X$, up to linear equivalence. As explained in Hartshorne IV.4, every degree-zero divisor is linearly equivalent to $p - p_0$ for some point $p \in X$, and this point $p$ is unique. Thus we have a bijection between points in $X$ and divisor classes in $Pic^0(X)$, given by:
$$ p \ \ \ \ \longleftrightarrow \ \ \  \ \ p -_{\rm divisor \\ minus} p_0 $$

*The elliptic curve group law is inherited from the group structure of $Pic^0(X)$ via this correspondence.* In other words, $$ p +_{\rm group \\ \ law} q \ =\  r $$
holds precisely when
$$
\left( p -_{\rm divisor \\ \ minus} p_0 \right) +_{\rm divisor \\ \ \ add} \left( q -_{\rm divisor \\ \ minus} p_0 \right) \sim_{\rm \ divisor \\ equivalence} \left( r -_{\rm divisor \\ \ minus} p_0\right), $$
and this is true precisely when
$$r \sim_{\rm \ divisor \\ equivalence}  \left( p +_{\rm divisor \\ \ add} q -_{\rm divisor \\ \ minus} p_0 \right)$$

[Here, "divisor equivalence" means "linear equivalence".]

---

Returning to the question you asked, we are presented with a divisor $D$ of degree zero. As mentioned above, we have
$$D \sim_{\rm \ divisor \\ equivalence} \left( p -_{\rm divisor \\ \ minus} p_0 \right)$$ for some unique $p \in X$.

$\tau_q$ is the transformation $p \mapsto p +_{\rm group \\ law} q$, which implies that
$$\tau_q^\star D \sim_{\rm \ \ \ divisor \\ equivalence} \left(p -_{\rm group \\ \ \ law} q \right) -_{\rm divisor \\ \ \ minus} \left(p_0 -_{\rm group \\ \ law} q\right)$$

Your question is whether we can prove that
$$ \tau_q^\star D \sim_{\rm \ divisor \\ equivalence} D.$$

Well, let's try and prove this. In view of the fact that $$\left( p -_{\rm group \\ \ \ law} q \right) +_{\rm group \\ \ \ law} q =  p,$$
and in view of our above characterisation of the group law on the elliptic curve, we have
$$\left( p -_{\rm group \\ \ \ law} q \right) \sim_{\rm \ divisor \\ equivalence} \left( p +_{\rm  divisor \\ \ \ add} p_0 -_{\rm  divisor \\ \  minus} q \right)$$

Similarly, replacing $p$ with $p_0$, we have
$$\left( p_0 -_{\rm group \\ \ \ law} q \right) \sim_{\rm \ divisor \\ equivalence} \left( p_0 +_{\rm  divisor \\ \ \ add} p_0 -_{\rm  divisor \\ \  minus} q \right).$$

Taking the difference of the above two equations, we have
$$ \left(p -_{\rm group \\ \ \ law} q \right) -_{\rm divisor \\ \ minus} \left(p_0 -_{\rm group \\ \ law} q\right) \sim_{\rm \ \ \ divisor\\ equivalence} \left( p -_{\rm divisor \\ \  minus} p_0 \right)$$
which confirms that $\tau_q^\star D \sim_{\rm \ \ \ divisor \\ equivalence} D$, as required.

Comment: Excuse me,please tell me where the fact which every degree zero divisor is linearly equivalent to $p-p_0$  is mentioned in the book.\\Besides this,I can understand,thank you very much!!

Comment: @GreenTea This is a consequence of Riemann-Roch. It is proven explicitly in Hartshorne IV.1.3.7. It is then mentioned again in Hartshorne IV.4 within the subsection called "The Group Law".

Comment: @GreenTea Here is the argument. Suppose $D$ is a degree-zero divisor. Then $D + p_0$ is a degree one divisor. By Riemann-Roch, $h^0(D + p_0) - h^0(K - D - p_0) = \deg(D + p_0) + (1 - g)$. The genus $g$ is $1$, and since $K$ is trivial, $K - D - p_0$ has degree minus-one, which is negative, so $h^0(K - D - p_0) = 0$. Hence $h^0(D + p_0) = 1$. Therefore, there exists a unique effective divisor that is linearly  equivalent to $D + p_0$. Since this effective divisor is of degree one, it must be a single point, $p$. Thus $D + p_0 \sim p$ for a unique $p$.

Comment: Thank you,you've been so helpful.