# Translation divisor elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Related to this problem [Pullback of a translation map of a divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446400/pullback-of-a-translation-map-of-a-divisor) I would like to understand how translations act on degree d divisors. Given a translation $\tau$ of our elliptic curve $E$ we have that it acts on the Picard group sending a line bundle $\mathcal{O(D)}$ to $\mathcal{O}(\tau D)$. In other words, fixing a divisor of degree d $D$ gives us a map $E\rightarrow Pic^d(E)$ sending a point p to $\mathcal{O(\tau_p(D))}$ where $\tau_p$ is the translation by $p$. So the questions reduce to understand this map. For example for degree 1 divisors the map is an isomorphism since every point can be sends to another point so the map has degree 1. I would like to understand it for higher degrees (for example what is the degree of the map).

Comment: I fix a divisor of degree d, I take a point of the elliptic curve $p\in E$, then I associate to it the translation by $p$, $\tau_p$, and I send it to $\mathcal{O}(\tau D)$, so I am looking at all possible translated divisor of my divisor and I would like to understand the degree of the map. For one point divisor I can of course reach all other points. So let's say I have $\sum_{i=1}^d p_i$ as mine divisor, so we take all the possible divisors $\sum \tau_p(p_i)$ of degree d as p varies among all points of the curve. Is it more clear?

Comment: To make things explicit as in your linked answer, don't you need to mention the rational functions and the fact for every $p,q$ there exists one with divisor $p+q-r-O$ where $p+q = r+O = r$ in the group law ?

Comment: What the other post I linked does is to see that if I have p-q as a divisor then we translate both p and q, then those translations in the group law cancels as divisors. Starting from that you can define the map I wrote above. Now let's say I fix two points p+q as divisor and start translating them (I translate p to get p' and q to get q' and consider the divisor p'+q', the degree is preserved). This defines a map to $Pic^2$ and I want to see what is the degree of the map. The thing is that I have a map from E to itself but it depends on the degree of the divisor we pick.

Comment: For example my map is constant when $d=0$ and has degree 1 when $d=1$ and I wanted to see how it generalizes for a general degree.       Probably I shouldn't have linked that question

Comment: If $|D| = 0$ then $D - \tau_p D $ is the divisor of a rational function ie. $D - \tau_p D\simeq 0$ in the Picard group.  If $D = \sum_{i=1}^d  q_i-\sum_{j=1}^{d-1}  r_i$ so $|D| = 1$ and $D =  q_i+E, |E|=0$ then $D - \tau_p D\simeq E - \tau_p E+q_i-\tau_p q_i \simeq q_i - \tau_p q_i \simeq O - \tau_p O\simeq O - p$ which doesn't depend on $D$. Then you ask what happens for $|D| = 2$ ? Again $D = \sum_{i=1}^d  q_i-\sum_{j=1}^{d-2}  r_i$  then $D - \tau_p D\simeq q_i+q_j - \tau_p q_i-\tau_p q_j \simeq 2O - 2p $ and in general $D - \tau_p D\simeq |D| O - |D| p$

Comment: So what is the degree of the map?

Comment: Don't you have any idea ?

Comment: So what you are saying is that the map is essentialy the multiplication by d between elliptic curves which has degree $d^2$, right?

Comment: Multiplication by $d$ between elliptic curves which has degree $d^2$ ?? I'm saying what I wrote $\tau_p D = D+|D| p -|D| O$

Comment: Yes I got that, now the map from E to $Pic^d$ sends a point q to $D+dq-dO$. This is not so formal (I have to think how to make it formal): $Pic^d$ is isomorphic to our elliptic curve so our map should be the multiplication by d translated by D-dO, hence after translating by D-dO our map has degree $d^2$ and translation is 1:1, hence our map has degree $d^2$.

Comment: Why don't you make things precise ? $dq$ is not the multiplication by $d$ in the group law of $E$ but the multiplicity of a divisor.

Comment: My map sends a point q to a translation of dq, so up to a translation my map sends q to dq, hence it has degree $d^2$.